# Xarray - Count occurnces of each variable value grouped by month

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, python-xarray

I have data that has variable "phase_ID" with numbers that range between 1 and 8. I want to count the occurrences of each phase_ID for each month. Data has daily frequency and looks like

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:   (time: 1095)
Coordinates:
  * time      (time) datetime64[ns] 1979-01-01 1979-01-02 ... 1981-12-30
Data variables:
    phase_ID  (time) int64 8 2 6 4 5 6 6 4 8 3 5 8 3 ... 3 2 3 0 1 4 5 3 4 0 8 7
```

Sample data can be generated with

```
time_length = 365*3
time = pd.date_range(start='1979-01-01T00:00:00.000000000', freq='D', periods=time_length)
ds = xr.DataArray(np.random.randint(1,9, size=(time_length)), dims=['time'],
             coords={'time':time}).to_dataset(name='phase_ID')
```

I have tried this

```
for group in ds.amplitude.groupby(ds.phase_ID):
    single_phase = group[1].groupby('time.month').count()
```

But now there is a lot of merging to do.

Is there a simpler way that this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

xarray doesn't support this yet (though it might be supported in the future, see [this](https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/324) issue).

For now, you could consider using `flox`:

```
print(ds)
>> <xarray.Dataset>
>> Dimensions:   (time: 1095)
>> Coordinates:
>>   * time      (time) datetime64[ns] 1979-01-01 1979-01-02 ... 1981-12-30
>> Data variables:
>>     phase_ID  (time) int64 3 8 2 1 8 1 3 6 6 8 5 7 2 ... 5 4 2 3 3 3 5 1 5 2 6 3


import flox.xarray

flox.xarray.xarray_reduce(
    ds,
    ds.time.dt.month,
    ds.phase_ID,
    func="count",
    expected_groups=(range(1, 13), range(9)),
    isbin=[False, True],
    method="map-reduce",
)

>> <xarray.Dataset>
>> Dimensions:        (month: 12, phase_ID_bins: 8)
>> Coordinates:
>>   * month          (month) int64 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
>>   * phase_ID_bins  (phase_ID_bins) object (0, 1] (1, 2] (2, 3] ... (6, 7] (7, 8]
>> Data variables:
>>     phase_ID       (month, phase_ID_bins) float64 1.0 2.0 3.0 ... 6.0 7.0 8.0
```

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you want to group the data by their ID. Like ID 2 is a group that also contains the time information. If my understanding is correct, I am thinking `Xarray.DataArray.where()` can help. For your case, `ds.where(ds.phase_ID==8,drop=True)` will keep all the data points that satisfy the phase_ID==8 criteria. If you ask `ds.where(ds.phase_ID==8,drop=True).count()` will tell you how many points satisfy the criteria. You can also use `xarray.where(ds==8,1,np,nan)` (note this is `xarray.where` not `DataArray.where()` to mask the data.